# Rescaling and downcasting a float safely in C++

Tags: c++, downcast

I am trying to bin a float number `R` and I want to obtain its weight `wt` in an unsigned 8 bit integer format:

```
float R;
float edgeVal = rintf(R); // round to the nearest edge
float dR = R - edgeVal + 0.5f; // distance to the edge with a half-pixel offset
unsigned char wt = static_cast<unsigned char>( dR*256.f )); // allowed range [0; 255]
```

At the edge of the interval where `dR == 0.f`, we will get `wt=0`, but at the other edge where `dR == 1.f`, we will get `wt = 256` which will wrap around to 0, while we really want to get `wt = 255` in this case. What would be the proper code to achieve it?

Here is a 2-bit example for the range of variables:

```
wt = |0|1|2|3|
     ^       ^
     |       |
dR = 0       1
```

Comment: Would `dR*255.f` not be acceptable (instead)?

Comment: In that case, the maximum value of `wt = 255` would practically never occur for a uniformly distributed `dR`, except for the rare exceptional case of `dR==1.f` Also, I think multiplication by powers of 2 is much faster.

Comment: How can this question possibly have anything to do with either C or CUDA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the exact value of `1.0f` is the issue, you might want to *avoid getting this value* for `dR` in the first place. I would suggest a tiny change to your logic, replacing `rintf` by `floor` whose behaviour is easily predictable in all cases independently of any external factors:

```
float Radj = R + 0.5f;
float edgeVal = floor(R); // now Radj - 1 < edgeVal <= Radj
float dR = Radj - edgeVal; // 0 <= dR < 1
```

Now the original

```
static_cast<unsigned char>( dR*256.f ));
```

never overflows to 0.

For a few test values, the original code gives

```
R       edgeVal dR  wt
0       0       0.5     128
0.25    0       0.75    192
0.5     0       1       0
0.75    1       0.25    64
1       1       0.5     128
1.25    1       0.75    192
1.5     2       0       0
1.75    2       0.25    64
2       2       0.5     128
```

while with `floor` the values of `edgeVal` and `wt` are consistent (at the cost of adjusting the former):

```
R       edgeVal dR  wt
0       0       0.5     128
0.25    0       0.75    192
0.5     1       0       0       // note the change here
0.75    1       0.25    64
1       1       0.5     128
1.25    1       0.75    192
1.5     2       0       0
1.75    2       0.25    64
2       2       0.5     128
```